# MySQL Query with Left Join and having clause

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a problem with a query can you tell me where I'm wrong? 
I have 3 tables:

> users:

```
 `users` (
  `id` int(11)  AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(16),
  `last_name` varchar(16) 
  `email` varchar(16)
  `password` varchar(32)
  `phone` varchar(13)
  `age` tinyint(4)
  `gender` varchar(6) 
  )
```

> users_eyes:

```
  `users_eyes` (
  `user_id` int(4),
  `user_eyescolor_id` tinyint(2),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`user_eyescolor_id`)
)
```

> users_eyestype:

```
  `users_eyestype` (
  `user_id` int(4),
  `user_eyestype_id` tinyint(2),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`,`user_eyestype_id`)
)
```

This is my query

```
SELECT 
                        SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
                        u.first_name, 
                        u.last_name,
                        u.age,
                        u.gender,
                        u.phone,
                        u.id
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ue.user_eyescolor_id SEPARATOR  ' ' ) as eyes_color 
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uet.user_eyestype_id SEPARATOR  ' ' ) as eyes_type
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_eyes ue ON u.id = ue.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_eyestype uet ON u.id = uet.user_id
WHERE
ue.user_eyescolor_id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING
COUNT(ue.user_id) = 4
```

and the result is a guy with 2 kinds of eyes, not this one with 4 kinds of eyes
everything is just perfect before i join and eyes_type.

Comment: Can you please show us your expected result? And let me know if you still need a solution. :-)

Comment: SELECT u.id
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ue.user_eyescolor_id SEPARATOR  ' ' ) as eyes_color 
, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT uet.user_eyestype_id SEPARATOR  ' ' ) as eyes_type
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users_eyes ue ON u.id = ue.user_id
LEFT JOIN users_eyestype uet ON u.id = uet.user_id
WHERE ue.user_eyescolor_id IN (1,2,3,4)
GROUP BY u.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ue.user_eyescolor_id) = 4

That slove my problem , slect the one who have all of eyes_colors

Comment: The only problem now is when i join 5-6 and more tables at a single query cuz , a need to do it. It takes a long time to finish my query

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to have test data to get you correctly.
Possibly you need COUNT(distinct ue.user_id) instead.

And no need LEFT JOIN users_eyes - inner join fits better as users_eyes fields used in where and having clauses.

**UPDATE**:
See [a fixed query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a05fa/4/0)

**EXPLANATION**:
If user has e.g. 4 users_eyes and 3 users_eyestype after join he/she gets 12 records (cartesian product). That's why **COUNT(ue.user_id)** failed.

**SOLUTION**:
Use COUNT(user_eyescolor_id) = 4 instead. In a future I would advice to change the query, though there is no easy workarounds.

Comment: there is user1 who have 4 rows user_eyescolor_id (IN(1,3) and
user2 , who have 2 rows user_eyescolor_id IN (1,2,3,4)
When i put my left join eyes_color i have the result i want(user1)
but when i add and left join eyes_type the reusult is user2.
i've tried with inner join the result is the same

Comment: The result is the same. I want to show the user with 
ue.user_eyescolor_id IN (1,2,3,4) but all of them.
in the concret situation the result is user with ue.user_eyescolor_id IN (1,3)